# IDisposable implementation in Abstract class hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class, idisposable

I am having following class hierarchy -

```
//Abstract Class1 in library1 (Can't modify this)
public abstract class absClass1 : IDisposable
{
    public abstract int AddTwoNumbers(int Num1, int Num2);
    // Some other overrides, abstract methods and concrete methods

    void Dispose()
    {
       // Standard Dispose impl.
    }
}

//Abstract Class2 in library2
public abstract class absClass2 : absClass1
{
    //Implementing AddTwoNumbers
    public override int AddTwoNumbers(int Num1, int Num2)
    {
       return Num1+Num2;
    }

    public abstract int MultiplyTwoNumbers(int Num1, int Num2);

    // Some other overrides, abstract methods and concrete methods

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!IsDisposed)
        {
            //Cleanup
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

//Derived class from absClass2 in library3
public sealed class absDerived1 : absClass2
{
    //Implementing MultiplyTwoNumbers
    public override int MultiplyTwoNumbers(int Num1, int Num2)
    {
       return Num1*Num2;
    }

    // Some other overrides, abstract methods and concrete methods

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!IsDisposed)
        {
            // Cleanup
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

//... Some more implementation of absClass2 like absDerived2 etc.
//  can be there in other library4...
```

I want to dispose objects in both `absClass2` and `absDerived`, is there any problem in overriding Dispose(bool) in both these classes? Is there any problem with this design? How can this be improved?

Comment: where do you execute GC.SuppressFinalize(this); ?

Comment: @MAfifi, I won't be using GC.SuppressFinalize as we are not using any destructors and don't want to automate the Dispose call, we ware relying on making sure that all objects are explicitly Disposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>This currently won't compile, but as you aren't asking why it doesn't compile I'm going to guess you just left out the `void Dispose()` definition for brevity.</sub>

This will be fine so long as you call into `base.Dispose` correctly and only worry about disposing the stuff local to the current class and not in a base class - as you are relying on `base.Dispose` to do this for you.

Calling `base.<member>` simply calls the direct base type of the current type, so in your case `absDerived` goes to `absClass2`, which goes to `absClass`.

My only observation would be you need to be careful on disposing the current type's stuff before calling `base.Dispose`. Depending on how stuff relates, you might want to dispose the base stuff first, then the current type - but this is entirely dependent on what you are actually disposing and if order is important.

Comment: Thanks Adam, yes I left Dispose() intentionally, it is in absClass1.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, regardless of the type of *reference* you have, if the *object* is `absDervied` then **once the absClass1 class Dispose() calls the virtual Dispose(bool)** then calling `Dispose()` on the reference will call the `Dispose` method on all the classes down to `absClass1`.

That method (on `absClass1`) calls the virtual method `Dispose(bool)`, which calls the most derived one (on `absDerived`) the `base.Dispose(disposing)` calls the method on the nearest base class (i.e. `absClass2`) which also contains a call to `base.Dispose(disposing)` which calls the method on `absClass1`.

Put that class structure in a console app, put some WriteLine statements in the Dispose methods, you'll see them all fire when `Dispose()` is called.